# Django login not working for a non www URL

Tags: django, django-login

So I shifted my website from a https://www.example.com URL to a https://example.com and now the login somehow stopped working. I am not sure why!

Comment: Could you post some code where you think the error might be happening? We're not mindreaders! :P

Comment: I've got to say this isn't much info to go off. You could at least start by describing "not working" - does the URL not load, do you get an error, etc.

Comment: @limelights all the code is unchanged, all I changed was the domain name

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I cannot login anymore even when I enter the username and password I get redirected back to the homepage and the response says user not logged in

Comment: Jonathan, don't be surprised, your post has no information what so ever. Your *comment* has more information than this post and I had to ask for it. Getting redirected to the homepage is a hint. Does the system detect invalid user/pass names? **Only valid combinations cause redirect?** What is the exact path of the redirect? Login URL -> Redirect URL.

Comment: Jonathan, it's not that. Your question is very openended and you've not supplied us with anything except "it's not working". Imagine you walking into a carshop with your car outside and saying "Fix it!" how is the mechanic supposed to know without YOU explaining whats wrong and how it came to be. Help us help you. It could be anything from code to server issues.

Comment: @limelights thats understandable, but you can just ask for more details if its not enough, usually when someone puts up a question on SO they are sick of trying to fix the problem and cannot find anything that would help them fix it. Its not that I enjoy not putting code up for users to help me. I had NO clue what was wrong. Thats why asked people this question hoping that someone else had encountered a similar problem and could help me with it, since the only thing that changed was the domain name, I did not feel the need to put any code up.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita I figured out the problem, it had to do with SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN

Comment: @Jonathan I understand your frustration with your problem, I really do. We've all been there but at a site like this it's really important to help us help you as we're doing this for fun and whilst you probably are getting paid for doing what you do so when you ask here you'll most likely not contribute any of your pay back to us. So it's really common sense to be as explicit as possible. Glad you got it working though! :)

Comment: @limelights :) no I do not get paid for what I do. I do it because I LOVE doing it. I keep another job just so I can come back home at night and work on this

Answer (score 0):

My Blind Answer :P

Make Changes to `settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] # not good for production env
```

Do something better like

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*.example.com']
```

Comment: Anish, I just had to change SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN to fix it